# How to configure durable-subscriber with spring in a cluster

Tags: jms, spring-integration, spring-jms

I have an application publishing some messages. Let's say a PaymentHasBeenMadeEvent

```
{ orderId:'1234'
  totalPaid:'$100'
  balanceStatus: 'BALANCED'
}
```

There are several applications care about the event. For example, the shipping application triggers a procedure on the event or the accounting application sends an email on the event.

So I want to publish this event using JMS durable-topic. I should configure each application with a unique client id as I've studied.

What confuses me is that the shipping application is deployed as a cluster with several nodes.  But I want the event to be consumed only once by the shipping application. How can I do that?

Or the solution is a flaw as I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use shared subscriber, which was added in  [JMS 2.0](https://jms-spec.java.net/2.0/apidocs/javax/jms/JMSContext.html#createSharedDurableConsumer(javax.jms.Topic,%20java.lang.String)). If you are using Spring 4.1, you can set the [subscriptionShared](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.html#isSubscriptionShared--) flag as true, so that only one instance in the cluster will receive the message. 
Worth referring [New Messaging Features in JMS 2.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jms2messaging-1954190.html) too.

Answer (score 0):

use the group syntax. Prepend each listener's topic with the same group.
i.e 
`[[payment_group_name]]payment.has.been.made`